# Query unprocessed rows with smallest dependency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to query the records that are not processed and with the lowest dependency. Each record can be dependent on an other record. I am not interested in the rows that have been processed.

```
USE tempdb
GO
DECLARE @Actions TABLE 
(
    Id int,
    DependencyId int,
    IsProcessed bit DEFAULT(0)
);
INSERT INTO @Actions
SELECT 1, NULL, 0
UNION SELECT 2, 1, 0
UNION SELECT 3, 2, 0
UNION SELECT 4, NULL, 1
UNION SELECT 5, 4, 1
UNION SELECT 6, 5, 0
UNION SELECT 7, NULL, 1
UNION SELECT 8, 7, 0
UNION SELECT 9, 8, 0;

SELECT * FROM @Actions;
```

The rows in this table:

```
1   NULL    0
2   1   0
3   2   0
4   NULL    1
5   4   1
6   5   0
7   NULL    1
8   7   0
9   8   0
```

As you can see:

- 1 has no dependency
- 2 is dependent on 1
- 3 is dependent on 2
- 4 has no dependency
- 5 is dependent on 4
- ...

The desired output is:

```
1, NULL, 0
6, 5, 0
8, 7, 0
```

because:

- 1: has not been processed and has no dependency
- 6: has not been processed and there is no other dependency that hasn't been processed.
- 8: has not been processed and there is no other dependency that hasn't been processed.

others should not be queries because:

- 2: has not been processed, but the dependency has not been processed yet
- 3: has not been processed, but the dependency has not been processed yet and its dependency (2) has an unprocessed dependency (1).
- 4,5,7: have been processed.
- 9: has not been processed, but the dependency (8) has not been processed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
;with ActionsWithDependentAction as (
  SELECT Act.*, dependentOnAct.IsProcessed as DependentOnActionIsProcessed
  FROM @Actions Act
  left outer join @Actions dependentOnAct on dependentOnAct.id=Act.DependencyId
)
SELECT Id, DependencyId, IsProcessed
FROM ActionsWithDependentAction 
WHERE IsProcessed=0 AND ISNULL(DependentOnActionIsProcessed,1)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
SELECT *
FROM @Actions
WHERE IsProcessed = 0
AND (
    DependencyId NOT IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM @Actions
        WHERE IsProcessed = 0
        )
    OR DependencyId IS NULL
    );
```